# How to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu^2(i)$ in less than $O(n)$'s time

Tags: time-complexity, discrete-mathematics, number-theory

To go with $O(n)$, we can use the **linear sieve** according to that $\mu(n)$ is multiplicative. But it seems that we don't have to work each $\mu(n)$ out and accumulate them together, because I only want to get $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu^2(i)$.

I am interested that is there any solutions that are faster than $O(n)$ to work $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu^2(i)$ out.

Comment: I suggest checking [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) to see if they list anything that is known about this sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mu^2(i)$ is 1 if $i$ is square-free, or 0 otherwise.  Therefore, your question is equivalent to asking how to count the number of square-free numbers in the range $1..n$.  That has been studied before; see, e.g.,

[Counting Square-Free Numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4890), Jakub Pawlewicz, arxiv 1107.4890.

That paper claims it can be computed in $\tilde{O}(n^{0.4})$ time (ignoring polylogarithmic factors).